# *** buffer overflow detected ***: ./lamps terminated

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am running a data acquisition program named LAMPS CAMAC. All of a sudden, I start getting the following error every time I try to a peak fitting of a pulse.

The error message is quite long, will try to embed it here.

```
    *** buffer overflow detected ***: ./lamps terminated
    ======= Backtrace: =========
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7338f)[0x7f0c2a23638f]
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__fortify_fail+0x5c)[0x7f0c2a2cdc9c]
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x109b60)[0x7f0c2a2ccb60]
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x109069)[0x7f0c2a2cc069]
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__printf_fp+0x2456)[0x7f0c2a214736]
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(_IO_vfprintf+0x315b)[0x7f0c2a20fe4b]
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__vsprintf_chk+0x84)[0x7f0c2a2cc0f4]
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__sprintf_chk+0x7d)[0x7f0c2a2cc04d]
    ./lamps[0x449638]
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0(g_closure_invoke+0x138)[0x7f0c2b2e03b8]
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0(+0x21d3d)[0x7f0c2b2f1d3d]
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0(g_signal_emit_valist+0xdd9)[0x7f0c2b2f9a29]
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0(g_signal_emit+0x82)[0x7f0c2b2f9ce2]
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0(gtk_widget_activate+0x7c)[0x7f0c2ba1052c]
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0(gtk_menu_shell_activate_item+0xfd)[0x7f0c2b912fed]
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0(+0x13f33c)[0x7f0c2b91333c]
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0(+0x12d815)[0x7f0c2b901815]
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0(g_closure_invoke+0x138)[0x7f0c2b2e03b8]
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0(+0x21afb)[0x7f0c2b2f1afb]
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0(g_signal_emit_valist+0xaa9)[0x7f0c2b2f96f9]
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0(g_signal_emit+0x82)[0x7f0c2b2f9ce2]
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0(+0x23d6b4)[0x7f0c2ba116b4]
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0(gtk_propagate_event+0xc4)[0x7f0c2b8fffc4]
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0(gtk_main_do_event+0x2db)[0x7f0c2b90037b]
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0(+0x5943c)[0x7f0c2b57a43c]
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0(g_main_context_dispatch+0x254)[0x7f0c2ae0ee04]
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0(+0x49048)[0x7f0c2ae0f048]
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0(g_main_loop_run+0x6a)[0x7f0c2ae0f30a]
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0(gtk_main+0xa7)[0x7f0c2b8ff447]
    ./lamps[0x407507]
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x7f0c2a1e4ec5]
    ./lamps[0x40761f]
    ======= Memory map: ========
    00400000-004b9000 r-xp 00000000 08:0b 523865                             /home/ananya/lamps_camac/lamps
    006b8000-006b9000 r--p 000b8000 08:0b 523865                             /home/ananya/lamps_camac/lamps
    006b9000-006bd000 rw-p 000b9000 08:0b 523865                             /home/ananya/lamps_camac/lamps
    006bd000-04159000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    04a3e000-0521b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
    7f0c08000000-7f0c08021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    7f0c08021000-7f0c0c000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
    7f0c0c000000-7f0c0c022000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    7f0c0c022000-7f0c10000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
    7f0c10000000-7f0c10022000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    7f0c10022000-7f0c14000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
    7f0c14000000-7f0c14049000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    7f0c14049000-7f0c18000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
    7f0c199ad000-7f0c1a3ae000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    7f0c1a3ae000-7f0c1a3af000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
    7f0c1a3af000-7f0c1abaf000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    7f0c1abaf000-7f0c1abb0000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
    7f0c1abb0000-7f0c1b3b0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    7f0c1b3b0000-7f0c1b3b1000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
    7f0c1b3b1000-7f0c1bbb1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00
```

524376 
....
.....
....
....
....
                                           [stack]
        7fff5e7fe000-7fff5e800000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
        ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
        Aborted (core dumped)

Comment: couldn't embed the full error message!

Comment: did you compile it from source yourself? try with the -g flag or cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug to track down which line caused the crash.

Comment: sorry i'm a novice in this field. where should I input the -g flag in the makefile?

Comment: is it a make file that comes with the source? add it to the CFLAGS definition line, or just insert it at the "gcc ...." line for the target, right after 'gcc' is fine, so you don't accidentally put it in between other flags/values

Comment: thanks will try it out! yes the makefile came along with the source.

Comment: hello, adding -g flag did not work. I get the same error message. can you provide any other solution please?

Comment: The -g option is to compile with debugging information. Now you should be able to find out where the culprit is, using addr2line. From your first example:  lamps crashed at 0x449638, to find out which line in source code caused the crash, do `addr2line -e lamps -a 0x449638` -e specifies the executable, -a address.

Comment: the Makefile is being shown as a non-recognized format with the addr2line command. Could you please elaborate a bit more, or should I attach the Makefile for your convenience?

Comment: what's the output when you run the add2line command in the terminal?

Comment: it shows file type not recognized.

Answer (score 0):

Please use an updated version of lamps from http://ambar-chatterjee.com/ or [https://www.tifr.res.in/~pell/lamps_files/download.html](https://www.tifr.res.in/%7Epell/lamps_files/download.html)